# Can i suppress Matlab Unit Test Framework's annoying call stack for warnings?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

Matlab's UT framework seems to print out a long call stack of internal methods of the framework itself. This results into an annoying flood of completely useless information if your test case causes lots of warnings. Is there a way to suppress the call stack but not the warning itself?

Example code:

```
classdef fooTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

    methods (Test)

        function bar(testCase)      
            testCase.verifyEqual(0,0);
            warning('!!!!!');
        end       
    end
end
```

Running the test:

```
>> result = run(fooTest);
Running fooTest
Warning: !!!!! 
> In fooTest/bar (line 7)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodCore (line 790)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodsOnTestContent (line 737)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestMethod (line 1061)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTest (line 1015)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/repeatTest (line 441)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runSharedTestCase (line 416)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestClass (line 943)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line 838)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestClass (line 407)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.testrunprogress.ConciseProgressPlugin/runTestClass (line 61)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line 696)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins (line 696)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestSuite (line 880)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line 838)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line 250)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.FailureDiagnosticsPlugin/runTestSuite (line 106)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line 696)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line 250)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.DiagnosticsRecordingPlugin/runTestSuite (line 184)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line 696)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line 250)
  In sltest.testmanager.plugins.TestManagerResultsPlugin/runTestSuite (line 60)
  In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line 696)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins (line 696)
  In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/run (line 288)
  In matlab.unittest.TestSuite/run (line 543)
  In matlab.unittest.internal.RunnableTestContent/run (line 48) 
.
Done fooTest
__________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

> > warning('off','backtrace')

Answer (score 1):

What version of MATLAB are you using? In more recent versions these stack frames are trimmed such that the framework stacks are not included but the relevant stack frames from the test down into the code being tested is still shown.

Your solution to turn of the stack frames entirely might be a good workaround for earlier versions, but it is a big hammer, and more recent versions should give you less extraneous information while still providing you with the information that is more likely to be useful.

Also, I would certainly encourage you to aim to run your test code without warnings at all. They can certainly be indicative of problems. In fact, you can configure your runner to be more strict and fail in the presence of these warnings to keep your testing clean. To do this use the [FailOnWarningsPlugin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.failonwarningsplugin-class.html), or [runtests(..., 'Strict',true)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/runtests.html?s_tid=doc_srchtitle#btzwrop-Strict). In the event that you do indeed have a valid warning you should be able to test against that using the [verifyWarning](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.verifiable.verifywarning.html) method or [IssuesWarnings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.issueswarnings-class.html) constraint, which works well with this workflow and does the right thing. Finally, if there is a case where you aren't testing for a warning but for some reason you can't avoid the warning being issued you can leverage the [SuppressedWarningsFixture](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.fixtures.suppressedwarningsfixture-class.html?s_tid=doc_ta).

Hope that helps,

Andy

Comment: Thanks for the tips @AndyCampbell. I'm using R2017B but just out of curiosity, I tested with R2018B after posting the original question. The annoying call stack didn't appear.